# Pressure forces integral on a closed surface = $0$?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, path-integral

I can understand why the flow rate through a closed surface is zero. But I saw in several lessons especially when it comes to the calculation of the turbojet engine thrust (with the Reynolds transport theorem), that $\int_{S} p \vec{dS} = \vec 0$ where $S$ is a closed surface, $p$ is the pressure, and $\vec{dS}$ is the surface element facing outward. Why the sum of the pressure forces on a closed surface is equal to $0$?

Can someone explain this physical concept?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The system would need to be in equilibrium. (I think. Fluids was the worst class I took in undergrad.) So what would equilibrium mean for the total vector sum of pressure forces on the inside of a container of fluid?

Comment: Well, I don't know what to say except that it is the integration of the pressure applied in a specific control surface of a specific control volume. We want to apply the derivation of the momentum of a fluid particle on a control volume. The complete equation after several mathematical manipulations is known as the Reynolds transport theorem :$\iiint_{CV} \frac{\partial \rho \vec v}{\partial t} dV + \iint_{CS} \rho \vec v (\vec v . \vec{dS}) = \iiint_{CV} \rho \vec g dV  - \iint_{CS} p \vec{dS}$ (+ a viscosity term but we consider here a perfect fluid, so viscosity is $ = 0$).

Comment: Hint: Pressure is a force. What would a non-zero result mean for the total force on the fluid inside the volume?

Comment: It means that the fluid inside the volume is moving.